# Python : Cannot save plots as png

Tags: python, matplotlib, word-cloud

I am trying to save pyplot plots as png as

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # take relative word frequencies into account, lower max_font_size
    wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=40, relative_scaling=.5).generate(text)
    fig = plt.figure()

    fig.savefig("../../results/plots/"+wf+".png")

    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

The plot is shown correctly but it always stores an empty image. Is something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: because you are saving it before you have plotted anything.  Move the save below `plt.axis(...)`

Comment: thanks man! that did it :)

Comment: You should write an answer to your own question so this gets marked as resolved.

Answer (score 3):

thanks @tcaswell, you are right. the solution is

```
fig = plt.figure()

plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
fig.savefig("../../results/plots/"+wf+".png")
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

i was trying to save before plotting